# GIthub action, authentication to git failed

Tags: git, github, yaml, github-pages, github-actions

I have a GitHub action with these steps:

```
    - name: Install dependencies
      run: npm install
    - name: Build
      run: npm run build
    - name: Git config
      run: |
        git config user.email "my_email@gmail.com"
        git config user.name "my_username"
    - name: Deploy
      run: npm run deploy
      env:
        github_token: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
```

where the npm deploy script is

```
gh-pages -b master -d build
```

so I'm basically pushing the build from the branch `develop` to `master`. 
The deploy script fails because it is not authenticating to git correctly. This is the error:

```
Run npm run deploy

> robertobatts.github.io@0.1.0 deploy /home/runner/work/robertobatts.github.io/robertobatts.github.io
> gh-pages -b master -d build

fatal: could not read Username for 'https://github.com': No such device or address

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! robertobatts.github.io@0.1.0 deploy: `gh-pages -b master -d build`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
```

The `secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN` should be created automatically by GitHub since I have set a workflow, so what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know precisely for your particular action, but usually, if the token is passed as an environment variable, it's in all-caps, like:

```
env:
  GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
```

Or if passed in as a parameter, using `with` instead of `env`:

```
with:
  github_token: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
```